# Howto dynamicly import a .js file in a .js file?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import

#### Duplicate question - see: [How do you dynamically load a javascript file? (Think C’s #include)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-think-cs-include)

---

Is there a javascript equivalent of @import? Because using the following way of including another javascript file from within a javascript file doesn't seem very nice and clean.

```
 document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='something.js'></script>");
```

Google has something which resembles what I'm looking for but it only works for their hosted files and I don't know how that functions works inside (all their code is compressed)

```
 google.load("maps", "2");
```

I need this because there are some javascript files that are only used sometimes in my app.