# jQuery: adding additional CSS files to current page

Tags: jquery, css

i have a website that uses **screen.css** as main CSS file. I added this for monitors with a 1024+ resolution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(screen.width > 1024) {
    $('link').attr('href','hi-res.css');
}
});
```

The problem is that hi-res.css is replacing screen.css... i don't want to replace it, i just want to load an additional css in that case. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Append it to your head:

```
$("head").append("<link id='yournewcss' href='hi-res.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to `.append` :o)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(screen.width > 1024) {
       $('head').append('<link href='hi-res.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />')
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. instead of replacing append one.

```
$('head').append($('<link>').attr('href','hi-res.css'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the following link:

[How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)