# Montserrat font czech characters render slightly lower than others

Tags: css, fonts, typography

I am trying to use web font Montserrat with czech characters.
But czech characters render slightly lower than others.

See screenshot from firefox:
[image: Montserrat czech chars]

font

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

css

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 1.25em;
```

Does anybody know how this issue is called in the typography and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font works fine on a Windows OS, the problem only occurs on a Linux OS. Since it's system related, Try converting it to a different format (the format used here is woff2, download the font and convert it to ttf or otf...)

Answer (score 0):

This is font related. My guess is that the font isn't compatible with czech characters.

Comment: i don't think so. Check https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat
There is clearly support for czech characters

Comment: I guess not .. cause I tested that out on jsfiddle it not the same result check this out https://jsfiddle.net/toa6tbjv/1/  (chrome and firefox browsers)

Comment: Okay I see, tried in every browser, and it seems to work just fine here.

Comment: @animake Well, you just reproduced my problem. But This doesn't imply that the font does not support czech characters.

Comment: I can see that the font indeed does support czech characters yes. But I didn't reproduce the problem. I used @animake's fiddle and it works fine in every browser.

Comment: @Rob as Marc said we didn't produce your problem, i guess it's system related. What OS are you using? windows, mac .. ?

Comment: @animake You don't see it on your fiddle? Ok ... I am using gnu/linux

Comment: My guess is @MarcHjorthLaustsen and I are using both windows, that should be your problem.

Comment: I just test it. It renders correctly on windows machine. Any pointers why it is happenning?

Comment: As for the solution, it's really hard to say since it's system related

Comment: Found this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726292/webfonts-rendering-differently-on-windows-mac-and-linux) with the same problem. [This article](https://www.owlfolio.org/htmletc/legibility-of-embedded-web-fonts/) is linked, which explains the phenomenon a bit. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: As for a solution, if you could code some javascript that detects OS (not sure if possible), and checks for czech characters, then change their font-size so it fits. This was just quick thinking.