# Import JavaScript files with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, import

Is it possible to use a CSS import file to import JavaScript pages?

```
@import url(Script.js);
```

Comment: What would you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Why in the world should that be possible? `:P`

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev My site only imports one URL in select pages. I have JavaScript for those pages but cannot add it in...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spec states the URL has to point to a style sheet:

> The '@import' rule allows users to import style rules from other style
>   sheets. Any @import rules must follow all @charset rules and precede
>   all other at-rules and rule sets in a style sheet. The '@import'
>   keyword must be followed by **the URI of the style sheet to include**. A
>   string is also allowed; it will be interpreted as if it had url(...)
>   around it.

**CSS3 Syntax Specification:** http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#import

Answer (score 5):

No, this syntax is not supported.

You can, however, use the `src` attribute of the [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script) element to specify the location of an external script resource:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I know that, I'm just asking since it would be cleaner to have one file

Comment: Well, since you want to reference an external script, you will always end up with at least two files... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only import CSS stylesheets or .less and .css stylesheets when using [Less](http://lesscss.org/). You can do it the other way around however and import [CSS stylsheets with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript).

Answer (score -3):

```
// Storing HTML code block in a variable
var codeBlock = '<div class="content">' +
                    '<h1>This is a heading</h1>' +
                    '<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>' +
                    '<p><strong>Note:</strong> If you don\'t escape "quotes" properly, it will not work.</p>' +
                '</div>'; 
// Inserting the code block to wrapper element
document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = codeBlock
```

How about this?