# Using CSS to include Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I don't think its possible, but I wanted to check with the 'experts'.

I only have CSS access to a site, is there anyway using CSS I can force in a JS file?

Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewCowley Do you want to include a file or would simply running a script sufficient?

Comment: @idmean All I want to do is be able to run JS on the site, but I only have CSS access. So running a script would be fine.

Comment: @idmean Already been mentioned in an answer, I hadn't seen this when i submitted the question, it hadn't come up.

Comment: @MatthewCowley That's an automatic comment because I voted to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @idmean Ah. Well I've my answer anyway it seems, which is no. But when I submitted the question, the 'duplicate' didn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, like your question is a duplicate of  [Import JavaScript files with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630625/import-javascript-files-with-css).

According to related post, it is not possible to load js file using @import rule inside css file.

CSS file can trigger loading following resources:

- other css files
- images
- fonts

Any attempt to return js script in response to css stylesheet request, will result in css parse errors in the browser.

Comment: Hadn't seen that when I submitted the question.

Comment: If it is a duplicate then please flag the post instead of posting an answer!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. At least as a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea, but you can use behavior (Work on IE9)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            behavior: url('script.htc');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And "script.htc":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hello world!');
</script>
```

Comment: OP said he only has css access.

Comment: put it on your css : body {
            behavior: url('script.htc');
        }

Comment: That is CSS, I can link it to an external script file.

Comment: @MBN Sadly it doesn't work on Chrome or Edge, so I can't really use it.

Comment: Only in old IE will that work to some extent.

Comment: I told you that's not a good idea :)