# CRM, Javascript and Dynamic CSS

Tags: javascript, css, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to include a link to a css file, but, the name changes.
The problem is, I am working with MSCRM 2011, and I am integrating a custom pop up window, that I need to have the "CRM style"

The link looks like this:

```
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/MyOrgtest/_common/styles/fonts.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-900509389">
```

The thing is, when I do it in a test environment (organization "MyOrgTest") the css link names includes the organization.

So, I need to, somehow, dynamically change this link, with something like a wildcard... I don't know, so I do not have to change the link manually.

Is this possible???

Comment: If I understand correctly you need the path to the css file to change dynamically?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the path. I can't use a fixed multilink solution and a javascript to select one of the links. It must be only one link, like:

<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/%DYNAMIC_NAME%/_common/styles/fonts.css.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-900509389">

And fill that %DYNAMIC_NAME% variable...

Comment: Did you deploy it as a web resource?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, then You can add an ID attribute to the link tag and set that %DYNAMIC_NAME% . Is that is what you are trying?

Comment: Yes, I deploy it as a webresource.

Comment: SKS, can you give me, please, an example of that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your solution (Settings > Solutions > Open your solution) and select "Web Resources" you should be able to add an html page like you have done with your css file. It will have a url just like your css file:

**<Microsoft CRM URL>/WebResources/<name of Web resource>**

You can then reference your css file by a relative path like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/fonts.css" />
```

An un-necessary alternative would be to dynamically generate the url of the css via javascript, using the context to get the server url:

```
var context = GetGlobalContext();
var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
var cssPath = serverUrl + "/WebResources/styles/fonts.css";
```

Once you had this you could check questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) to add the css file via javascript.