# Load/refer css file inside a javascript external file

Tags: javascript, css, external

How can I load/refer to an external CSS file inside an external JS file.

As shown in the below image I would like to refer/load Default.css inside Common.js

[image]

Thanks in advance

BB

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `link` tag in script, referencing your stylesheet.

Here's how you do it in jQuery:

```
$("<link/>", {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    type: "text/css",
    href: "your script here."
}).appendTo("head");
```

Comment: How can I use the styles which are inside the CSS file. for ex : $('#txtExp').css(TextNormal); throws an error. TextNormal is a style inside Default.css.

Comment: Once you load the CSS into the DOM, then those styles are available for assignment. What error are you getting? You may want to try `$("#txtExp").addClass("TextNormal");`

Comment: Is there an event you're doing this on? Like `$(document).ready?` Your CSS <em>must</em> be loaded into the DOM before this will work, i.e., you need to load your CSS before you try to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a stylesheet "inside" JavaScript, you need to add the stylesheet to the DOM.

The link **grc** posted as a comment tells you how.

[How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a `<link>` element and append it to `document.body` after adding proper attributes (`href`, `type` etc) to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try and find the absolute path of the file Default.css within the application.

From Common.js, you would be able to load Default.css using something like this:

```
var linkEl = document.createElement('link');
linkEl.href='/App_Themes/Default/Default.css'; // start with slash '/' for absolute path
linkEl.rel='stylesheet';
linkEl.type='text/css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkEl);
```