# Are there tools to simulate race conditions related to web resources (e.g. css arriving 500ms after html+js)?

Tags: race-condition

I would like to test that my code does not exhibit a race condition where css files are served slowly. Is there a tool that can help me test this?

Fiddler has "simulate modem speeds", but I can't specify that only css files should be delayed.

Any other quick suggestions? (I don't want to spend too much time on setting this up, this should be a drop in tool that just does the job).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddler Delayed Responses Extension](http://fiddlerdelayext.codeplex.com/) seems to be what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSS styles with the [Web Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) (there are seperate Chrome and Firefox downloads).

If this isn't acceptable you could reference this StackOverflow question to put some JavaScript on the page:
[How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

and wrap it in a

```
setTimeout(function() { // code here }, millisecondsDelay);
```

to delay the loading however long you'd like.

Comment: This is not what I had in mind, sorry. I don't want to disable css, nor do I want to change how they are loaded - this changes the semantics.