# html link tag for importing css where to place in case of AJAX

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have a page which loads different pages within a div. Now the pages that are being loaded do have their own style sheets.

If i'm loading the other page, where should the `<link rel="text/stylesheet...>` should be present? Because once the page is loaded, i can see in the source that the link is residing inside the `<body>`. The other `<head>` and `<html>` tags are removed automatically by the browser but `<link>` stays in between the divs.

Now I don't know is it wrong or right. Please guide me further!

---

**EDIT**

There is a main page that loads with its own css. This page has a div in which the content is to be fetched via ajax as per user's request.

When the ajax request is made the server returns the content to be loaded in that div which comes with its own css.

Now the problem is where should i put the css in my response content? Because the css is in external file and to link it the ` tag must be in head of your html? I think so.

But when i view source, i get the css `<link>` between the divs.

Comment: How are you loading the pages into the div?

Comment: using ajax, i am making a call to the server which returns the part to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just add them to your main head section. They will apply to the added html. Your loaded pages don't need an own html sceleton at all. Just the html you want to add dynamicly.

But if you really want to load the css files dynamicly too, just add the link tag with javascript as shown here: [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript).

In your case this could look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    beforeSend: function() {
        if (!$('#testcss').length) {
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" id="testcss" />')
                .appendTo('head');
        }
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#pagediv').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: but at first load the main page will have to load too much css that may or may not be necessary to the user?

Comment: How many css do you have that this could be a performance problem? :P

Comment: 5-600 lines per file for maybe 6 files?

Comment: If the html is loaded it'll take extra time to load css?

Comment: How does your ajax call look like?

Comment: just putting the data returned on success into a div as `$('.some-div').html(data);`. The call is POST and return type is normal text.

Comment: Then use `beforeSend` callback of jquerys `$.ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/