# Different CSS in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i currently have been looking at the following:

```
if (window.top!=window.self) { 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.website.com/content/themes/theme/style.css" type="text/css" />
} else { 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.website.com/content/themes/theme/iframe.css" type="text/css" />
}
```

I want to add linked files, so when it loads on the website styles.css will load, and when in a frame it will load frame.css what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixing JS with HTML.

Comment: you are mixing javascript with HTML.

Comment: @rupps, are you my evil twin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing JavaScript with HTML. That's why you will get syntax errors.

You need to use a function that [will load a CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574944/1420197):

```
function loadCSSFile (filename) {
      var fileref = document.createElement("link");
      fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
      if (typeof fileref != "undefined");
         document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
function loadCSSFile (filename) {
    $("<link>", {
         rel: "stylesheet"
       , type: "text/css"
       , href: filename
    }).appendTo("head");
}
```

Then you will do:

```
if (window.top!=window.self) { 
    loadCSSFile("http://www.website.com/content/themes/theme/style.css");
} else { 
    loadCSSFile("http://www.website.com/content/themes/theme/iframe.css");
}
```

Comment: if this was on wordpress website, where do i put the JavaScript of jQuery any ideas? I'm guessing the if statement will be on the page header?

Comment: @user3348182 It really doesn't matter in this case. Just wrap the code using `<script>...</script>` tags and it should work.

Comment: Im afraid i can't get this working it will be simple I'm just probably doing something wrong i need to load this in <HEAD> part of the document its not loading any of the CSS files not even the original :/ any help?

Comment: You need to do the top one for anyone who needs it in the future! FANTASTIC! Thank you!