# HTML conditional statement if IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I never thought that I am stupid, but... I found hundreds of ways to create if statement in html. Some says that right way is:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   You're using IE!
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
   You're using something else!
<![endif]>
```

Or this:

```
<![if !IE]>
//code
<![endif]>
```

Or look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APFZh/2/

All of this DON'T works on my pc. Why? All says that "you have to do this..." and such answers are suggested, so they have to contain working examples, but...

Why they don't work in my browsers? What is the correct way to write conditional statements? Is example from fiddle is working?

[image]

I tried to open fiddle in ie 11, not with FF and changed useragent. Epic.

Why it is so ? What I have to do? Help me please!

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me in IE9.

Comment: As, @DrydenLong noticed, they works fine if IE lt 10

Comment: it is called conditionnal **comment** , so you start with : `<!--` and end with : `-->` condition is to be written in between `[if ...]>` HTML if condition matches  `<[endif]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conditional comments were disabled in IE10 so they will not work in IE11.

[Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

In order to have conditional statements you can use Javascript to detect the browser. Since I see Mootools in your screenshot, [here is a guide on how to do that.](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2010/10/how-to-detect-browser-using-mootools-1-3-javascript/)

Or, here is a JS library that is pretty good: [WhichBrowser](http://whichbrowser.net/)

That being said, browser sniffing is not recommended. Look into [Feature Detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_Feature_Detection) instead.

Comment: Okay. I thought it is not simple task, isn't it? I mean detecting user agent with JS. Is there a way to do this without external library? Also, why conditional not works in ff?

Comment: So, I have to use WhichBrowser to detect browser and use for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/577002/2898694) method to load css, right?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav That's one way of doing it, yes.

Comment: Mhm. There are no link to download `detect.js`. https://github.com/NielsLeenheer/WhichBrowser Readme says, that I have to upload detect.js to dir in my site and make reference in my html code.

Comment: That's probably a question for the developer then. I've never used WhichBrowser before so I have no idea about it's dependencies...

Comment: Okay. I will better download and user mootols then. +88 kb :( Nice chance to add tooltips :)

Comment: ARgh!!! But I need to play with some elements in code. How I can do this easily with JS :'( HTML conditionals were the solution... =/

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Google "Javascript browser detection" and you should find plenty of tutorials. If you get stuck with one of them, come back and post a new question with the code you are having problems with.

Comment: Nono. I know how to detect browser now :) Mootools provides good object for it. I meant how to manage elements on page, using js.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It seems like a broad question. You may want to start a new question since this one is starting to get off-topic.

Comment: Solution for what I meant: using css class with display: none for example; another solution: use JS to remove/add items to the dom.

Answer (score 2):

You are not closing the comment tags correctly - it should look like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
   You're using IE!
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
   You're using something else!
<![endif]-->
```

For extensive information on Conditional Statements see - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As I said! 1 more suggestion to make this another way. This not worked.

Comment: Tested it with IE9 and it works like this. In any case you need to have your syntax straight. The Conditional Statement is basically wrapped inside a HTML comment tag `<!-- -->`

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because OP is using IE11 and conditional comments were disabled in IE10. No matter the syntax, it will not work in IE10 or IE11

Comment: My bad - I overlooked that he is trying to use IE11. I was just looking at the code ;)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Yes, conditional comments work in IE9 and below