# special css load for iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

**The plan:**

I have an `iframe`, called `frame.html`. If the `frame.html` is shown alone (not inside a page) it should load the `no_frame.css`.

If the frame.html is shown as an `iframe` inside a page it should load the `frame.css`.

The CSS should change divs inside the `frame.html`, so its important that the script check out if the page stays alone or inside an `iframe`. And I want to use this script in general for `iframes`, not only for the `iframe.html`.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

@Alex K. - like this??:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if (window!=window.top) { framed=true }

    var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
    {
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.id   = cssId;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = 'http://website.com/css/frame.css';
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (window!=window.top) { framed=true }` then [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Comment: And if the difference between frame.css and no_frame.css is minimal, you can alternatively add a flag and scope the relevant css

Comment: @Neps: how will this look like? Primary I only want to "display:none" some divs.

Comment: Pretty sure I suggested the same thing @Neps just said on the same question earlier today already … so why did you delete it (assuming that was yours, which I think was the case)?

Comment: Follow @AlexK.'s comment, then also add a class i.e.`<body class="framed">`. From there, you only need to maintain 1 stylesheet.

Comment: Sry, my js skills are very low - so is my script on top wrong?