# Is there a way to include css files through variable in HTML file?

Tags: css, html, template-engine

I'm looking for a way to include css files through variable in html file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- variable = "/css/style.css" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=variable>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=variable>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Do anything -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what language? Are you doing this at `php` level (server side) or do you want to do it after the page loads, via `javascript` (client side)? For both, the answer is **yes, it's possible**.

Comment: I will do in client side and before the page loads.

Comment: This question is rigth here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript

Comment: plus one for the protoss avatar <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using JavaScript ... Create a JavaScript variable and according to its value change the value of the `href` attribute something like this

```
<link href="url.css" id="selector" type="text/css" />
<script> var variable = 'value`;  </script>
...
<script>
if (variable) {  // Or whatever you need to do
  document.getElementById("selector").href = "another.css";
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's simple. Why didn't I know this way.

Answer (score 0):

This also works....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    var target = document.createElement("script");
                    target.type = "text/javascript";
                    target.src = "script/knockout.js";
                    document.getElementById('head').appendChild(target);

                    var cssTar = document.createElement("link");
                    cssTar.rel = "stylesheet";
                    cssTar.type = "text/css";
                    cssTar.href = "Scripts/StyleSheet1.css";
                    document.getElementById('headid').appendChild(cssTar);
           </script>
```