# How to pick CSS file with javascript if

Tags: javascript

Would it be possible for me to do something like

`<link href="nav.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

in this?

```
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
        Link to css here!
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries? This takes the JavaScript completely out of it

Comment: `if (something){var link = document.createElement("link");link.setAttribute("href", "nav.css");link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a css media query like so

You can read about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
@media(max-width: 800px) {
    /*
     * enter css here
     */
}
```