# any way to include js ref and css ref as a single ref?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do you know if there's a way to include a js ref and css ref as a single ref in html? Normally these refs are included separately in the html head but my manager wants to know if there's a simplified way for downstream consumers to add these refs as a single ref.

Comment: do you use any kind of server scripting ?

Comment: An included JS file can add a CSS link when it runs.

Comment: or as @nnnnnn said, but if answer to first question is yes ,you could inject them into file before it's downloaded, then you get all files at cost of 1 request

Comment: @nnnnnn – But that may affect the layout...

Comment: An `include()` php function will do. Make a separate php file containing the js and css refs and call it on the head of your html. (no php tag included though, just an idea..... :v )

Comment: @Rayon - Even if included in the `<head>`? Either way, I'm not aware of another way to do it. (I don't see how server-side stuff could help for "downstream consumers".)

Comment: @nnnnnn you take the contents of the css file (that file must contain css inside <style> tag) and js file(that file must contain script inside <script> tag ), and inject them directly into final html ?

Comment: @MarkoMackic - Well yes, but I don't think that's "simplified" for downstream consumers, because it forces them to use some server-side coding on their page rather than using a simple html-based include, and that may not be possible for some users.

Comment: Is there any type of tool or automated build task that can take a js file and a css file and concatenate them together into a single js file or some other relevant modern file type that would be usable for this type of implementation? This would further simplify the downstream client implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your CSS as a string in your JavaScript:

```
var myStylesheet = 
  'body { background-color: blue; }
   #my-div{ background-color: white; }'
  ;
```

Then:

```
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.type = 'text/css';
styleElement.innerHTML = myStylesheet;
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
```

This creates a style element and places it in the document head.

It is equivalent to:

```
<head>
  ...
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: blue; }
    #myDiv { background-color: white; }
  </style>
</head>
```

This is the bundling approach used by, for example, the [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) library; see, for example, the `inject` function defined at [line 42](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/build/dat.gui.js#L42) of the un-minified build, and the (very lengthy!) style string at [line 2857](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/build/dat.gui.js#L2857).

Answer (score 3):

One possible way would be to include only the JavaScript, and within it, to load your CSS.

Take a look here:
[How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)