# How can I serve different style sheet file based on a condition in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, stylesheet

Suppose I have two style sheet file:  *style.css* and *style-rtl.css*
which second is for right to left support. How can I serve different style sheet file based on a condition in Angular 2. Notice that one of them should be applied.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript. Then just import the files using javascript

Comment: @AndreiTumbar Well, it's kinda different in Angular 2.