# Javascript Print gridview in Div with CSS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, printing

I'm trying to print a particular DIV.
there are few lines of header, and there is a gridview with some css applied.
after a long search, I found a way to print the div to a different page, in order to not loose the focus on the main page. 
the problem is that the gridview is printed without any border, and it's useless in that way.
I guess the problem is the CSS that I used for the gridview, but I don't know how to solve this.

this is the div

```
<div id="tabella">
<asp:label font-bold="true" Font-Italic ="true" ID="lbIdStabile" Text="Cod. Stabile: " runat="server"> 
<asp:label Text='<%# Bind("Id")%>' ID ="lbIdStb" runat="server"/></asp:label>
<br />
<asp:label ID="TextBox1" font-bold="true" Text='<%# Bind("indstab")%>' runat="server"/>
<br /> <br />
<asp:GridView ID="GrigliaPdr" CssClass="gridtext align-left table table-bordered" runat="server" RowStyle-Wrap="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlPDR" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAlternate" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="gridSelect"  showheader ="true">
<Columns>      
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" Visible="False"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="piano"  HeaderText="Piano" /> 
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
<br />       
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("data_odierna", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</div>
```

this is my print function

```
function printDiv(divName) {
var prtContent = document.getElementById(divName);
var WinPrint = window.open('');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

and this is the button that calls the print function

```
<asp:Button ID="BT_PrintPDR" runat="server" class="win-command"  title="Stampa PDR" cssclass="icon-search" Text="Stampa PDR" type ="button" OnClientClick="printDiv('tabella');" > </asp:Button>
```

any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add references to your original CSS files into the document contained by `WinPrint`. You can do this by adding the following lines between the 4th and 5th line of your `printDiv` function:

```
 var head  = WinPrint.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var link  = WinPrint.document.createElement('link');

 link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
 link.type = 'text/css';
 link.href = 'http://yourWebSite/css/yourCSSFile.css';
 link.media = 'all';
 head.appendChild(link);
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 1** 
Here's an excellent answer to [load CSS files using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Comment: That's great Alfaking. If it is ok for you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS add media query for print and apply the same styling to get border and other things.
Let me know if it works for you!