# Load css on angular application based on subdomain

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli, subdomain

**Todo :**

- css file based on subdomain loaded. 
  **For e.g:** I have abc.css, xyz.css and these css should be loaded based on subdomains like if abc then abc.css must be loaded and so on.

**Tried Cases :**

- Dynamically load css from angular-cli.json (Couldn't found a way to
  load dynamically)
- Loading css on index.html (MiME type issue encountered)
- Use style-loader on app init e.g require("style-loader!./style.css");

**Used version :**  Angular 4.4.6 version.

Can anyone help me on this?

I am open to all suggestions, please suggest.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the HTML template:
`<link rel="stylesheet" [href]="getCssUrl()">`

In the component.ts:

```
constructor (private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

getCssUrl() {
    // Implement your code to return CSS url based on sub-domain
    const cssURL = xxx;
    return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(cssUrl);
}
```

Comment: Encountered issue: unsafe value used in a resource URL context.. while returning '../custom.css' from the function.

Comment: Using DomSanitier will fix above issue but encountered another issue: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/custom.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: If `dom-sanitizer` is not helpful then you can refer to this issue on github : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4685#issuecomment-279746337
Also, this if you can manipulate plain javascript in angular using renderer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript
Hope, it helps.

Comment: Have you tried sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl() method? I just edited my answer earlier.

Comment: If you still have MIME type issue, try to remove rel="stylesheet" from the html template.

Comment: I have found a blog post talking about the same solution as mine, and it does mention another solution using webpack. https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/

Comment: I want to have file name based on sub-domain. removing rel-'styylesheet' remove MIME issue but not working as expected