# React Dynamic Themes

Tags: reactjs, sass, themes

I have a React 16 app and would like to allow the user to change the theme for the entire app (including all Routes) by pressing a button.

So for example, I could have two themes in SCSS:

```
.theme-1 {
    background-color: $bg-color-1;
    color: $color-1;
}
.theme-2 {
    background-color: $bg-color-2;
    color: $color-2;
}
```

Then I would have a button as follows:

```
<Button onClick={ this.changeTheme() }
```

Can this be done? Specifically, I want to figure out these two parts:

1. How to set the theme on all components that need to use the various `background-color` and `color`.
2. The logic of the `changeTheme()` function. How exactly it would go about triggering a re-render on all affected components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do it is by using [css variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp).

You need to specify your theme using css variables and on some user action add additional css in your site.

1. Create **single** theme like you have mentioned above

   ```
    --color: blue;
    --bg-color: red;
    .theme {
        background-color: var(--bg-color);
        color: (--color);
    }
   ```
2. Add additional styles right inside your component

   ```
   {this.state.useTheme && <style type="text/css">
       :root {
           --color: blue;
           --bg-color: red;
       }   
   </style>}
   ```
3. Change flag on user click

   ```
   <div onClick={this.setState({useTheme: true})}> Apply theme </div>
   ```

or another variant

2. Create additional `theme.css` file where you specify different variables

   ```
   --bg-color: yellow;
   --color: green;
   ```
3. attach it on some user action. Code source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

   {
          var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          var link  = document.createElement('link');
          link.id   = cssId;
          link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
          link.type = 'text/css';
          link.href = 'http://your-website.com/path-to-css-file/theme.css';
          link.media = 'all';
          head.appendChild(link);
      }}> 
          Change theme

By doing like that you will avoid a lot of code duplication. Because you don't need to create multiple themes. You only need to add small additional css on change, so you can create a lot of themes or even let user to customize them.

Comment: css variable are not supported by all the browsers, in that case how will it fallback

Comment: @atul almost nothing is supported by **all** browsers. [css variables are supported by all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var). The only reasonable concern is IE11 in that case. [But IE11 is less than 1% of total users](https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). [And most likely supporting those users isn't wise.](https://medium.com/@burger.neal/the-end-of-life-of-internet-explorer-11-12736f9ff75f).