# <Link> external resources using typescript variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-resource

I have the external link to the css file stored as string variable in typescript component. I want to use in a *link* tag in html to import the external css file for my web theme. I have defined the link variable as below.

```
matlink:string="http://localhost:8000/static/css/mat-header/theme.css";
```

Then I am trying to import in the html file as

```
<link href="{{matlink}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However, in this case, no content is being shown. Is it possible to import resource file into html using some variable?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Angular 2 and above:

You can also bind to `[attr.href]="expression"`

And final code would be `<link [attr.href]="matlink" rel="stylesheet"/>`