# Is it possible to change css stylesheets after a page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, function, stylesheet

I am trying to add a "dark mode/light mode". I am trying to do this by using two different CSS style sheets and having a single button to click through them

ive tried using setAttribute, innerHTML, removeAtribute( moving the contents of one style sheet into  tags and trying to remove one stylesheet)

change to Light Mode

```
function light(){

    document.getElementById(css).setAttribute("href", "LIGHTMODE.CSS")
    document.getElementById(darkmode).innerHTML="Change to Light Mode"
    document.getElementById(darkmode).onclick="dark()"
    cos
}

function dark(){

            document.getElementById(css).href = "LIGHTMODE.CSS"
            document.getElementById(darkmode).innerHTML="Change to Dark Mode"
            document.getElementById(darkmode).onclick ="light()"
            console.log(darkmode)
    }
```

It should identify the  throught the Id and  change the href to whatever is stated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both stylesheets loaded, and enable/disable them at will

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkmode.css" class="css dark">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightmode.css" class="css light" disabled>

<script>
    function setcssmode(s) {
        document.querySelectorAll('link.css').forEach(ss => {
            ss.disabled = !ss.classList.contains(s);
        })
    }
    setcssmode('dark');
    setcssmode('light');
</script>
```

In this example, the light stylesheet is disabled on page load.

The benefits of doing it this way is that the stylesheet that is disabled is still loaded on page load, therefore the switch will be instantaneous, rather than potentially delayed while the CSS for the alternative style is loading

Answer (score 0):

If you just add `href` to an existing element, browser would not automatically fetch the new CSS.

By the way, both your `dark` and `light` function are using same CSS namely `LIGHTMODE.CSS` , maybe you want to use `DARKMODE.CSS` inside dark

```
function dark(){
 // Get HTML head element 
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];  

        // Create new link Element 
        var link = document.createElement('link'); 

        // set the attributes for link element  
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';  

        link.type = 'text/css'; 

        link.href = 'DARKMODE.CSS';  

        // Append link element to HTML head 
        head.appendChild(link);  
}
```