# Google appmaker checkbox style broken

Tags: google-app-maker

This may not be the right place to ask but did Google update their style? Everything is whacky! And Regular and Dark styled checkboxes are not showing properly even though they do seem to assume values.

I don't see the changes in the templates, so maybe I did something wrong somewhere, but I don't recall messing with global styles or anything like that.

Can someone help me understand what is going on? Thanks

[image]

EDIT: Answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) takes care of adding the css to the particular page through javascript, so adding the code into the onAttach function of the page takes care of my issue.

Comment: I don't think there is something changed. We definitely need more context. I believe might be some custom CSS involved. Check your page styles and your global styles.

Comment: I had a few global styles but independent of anything I am seeing wrong. I removed them anyway and the odd styles remain. I will try to add an image to the post.

Comment: @Morfinismo, Added a picture, can you make out anything?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Definetly is your app if you say there is no issue with the CSS. Have you tried the checkbox widget in a new app. Test it inside other app and if it works, the problem is this specific app you are using.

Comment: @Morfinismo,  Yes, I realized I had add a CSS URL in the settings of the app (materialize css). My question now is, how do I make the css available on a few select pages?

Comment: I really consider that as a bad idea. Instead you should right your own css and put it at the page level or use classes and put it at the global level. Nonetheless, if you insist and want to go through some painful time, then you can use the @import decorator at the page level css. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@import