# I cant add url to js function

Tags: javascript, css

```
<p>Click the button to add the "mystyle" class to DIV.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The classList property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="myDIV">
I am a DIV element
</p>

<script>

link.href = 'http://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/deneme.css';

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add.link.href;
}
```

simple question.I want to change color to red after click button.css file is only 1 line

Comment: What are you trying to do with `classList.add.link.href`?

Comment: Oh, I think I see.  You should add the class name, not the URL of the CSS file, to the div.  `document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add('mystyle')`

Comment: oh, I updated css file.please check it again,I want to add class

Comment: but I want to access class name from css file url

Comment: That's not how it works.  The page needs a `<link rel="stylesheet"/>` to pull in the css classes; you do not attach the link directly to the elements you want styled.

Comment: document.getElementById("myDIV").style.color = "red";

Comment: can you write a full example?

Comment: @ParthoKR its not my answer.I need to access css file from url to change font color to red as an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how classes or external stylesheets work.  What you want to do is link the stylesheet to the page, which makes the classnames and css rules it contains available; then you attach the classname to the element you want styled.

To link the stylesheet that contains the '.mystyle' class definition, include a link to it in the `head` of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/wp-content/themes/deneme.css">
```

Then change your script to add the classname, not the url, to the element:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add('mystyle');
}
```