# How i use javascript and css files on a innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, api

I'm developing a web application with node and I'm having a problem. What I want to do with the code below is to load the information of the backend after clicking on "RESERVAR" and put on my HTML (.ejs) file. The problem is that the HTML code runs nice on the HTML file, but when I transfer it on a js file, to add the backend information, the code doesn't run as I expected because it needs some js and CSS files to run. Because my js file doesn't suporte;

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/timedropper.css">
      <script src="../js/back-comunication.js"></script>
```

it doesn't seem to load the input correctly.

My app website: https://labmanagersite.herokuapp.com/

Bellow the code on my js file, that I'm trying to insert the HTML segment on my HTML file.

```
async function openReserva(id) {
  let endereco = `https://lab-manager.herokuapp.com/laboratorio/${id}`;
  const response = await fetch(endereco);
  const user = await response.json();
  document.querySelector(".reserva").innerHTML = `
      <div class="reserva-container">
      <div class="reserva-header">
        <h1>${user[0].nome}</h1>
        <p>${user[0].descricao} / ${user[0].capacidade} computadores</p>
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="reserva-inputs">                  
        <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0" checked>
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>            
        <div class="input-containers data-container"  style="max-width: 100% !important;">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            </div>   
            <input id="input-data2" class="input-data" value="0"   
              type="text" data-lang="pt" data-large-mode="true" 
              data-large-default="true" data-lock="from" 
              data-translate-mode="true" data-theme="my-style" 
              data-format="d/m/Y" data-max-year="2050" data-min-year="2000"/>                 
              <div class="select_mate" data-mate-select="active" id="select-date">
                  <select onclick="return false;" onchange="" onclick="return false;" id="">
                    <option value="0">Domingo</option>
                    <option value="1">Segunda</option>
                    <option value="2">Terça</option>
                    <option value="3">Quarta</option>
                    <option value="4">Quinta</option>
                    <option value="5">Sexta</option>
                    <option value="6">Sabado</option>                           
                  </select>
                  <p class="selecionado_opcion" onclick="open_select(this)"></p>
                  <span onclick="open_select(this)" class="icon_select_mate">
                    <svg fill="#FF9F2E" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z" />
                        <path d="M0-.75h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                  <div class="cont_list_select_mate">
                    <ul class="cont_select_int"> </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-containers horario-container" style="max-width: 100% !important;">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="select_mate" data-mate-select="active" >
              <select onclick="return false;" onchange="" onclick="return false;" id="">
                  <option value="0">01:00</option>
                  <option value="1">02:00</option>
                  <option value="2">03:00</option>
                  <option value="3">04:00</option>
                  <option value="4">05:00</option>
                  <option value="5">06:00</option>
                  <option value="6">07:00</option>
                  <option value="7">08:00</option>
                  <option value="8">09:00</option>
                  <option value="9">10:00</option>
              </select>
              <p class="selecionado_opcion" onclick="open_select(this)"></p>
              <span onclick="open_select(this)" class="icon_select_mate">
                  <svg fill="#FF9F2E" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z" />
                    <path d="M0-.75h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                  </svg>
              </span>
              <div class="cont_list_select_mate">
                  <ul class="cont_select_int"> </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>               
      </div>            
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Reservar</button>
      </div>                        
    </div>    
  `;
  const exit = document.querySelector(".reserva-header i");
  let reservaOpen = true;
  exit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (reservaOpen) {
      document.querySelector(".reserva").innerHTML = ``;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It sounds as though you need your JS file to load a css file - is that right? In which case it needs to do something like the accepted solution given in [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript/577002#577002 but I may have misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well, but why instead of using innerHTML, you keep the reserve-container div hidden and the only thing you do is that when the user clicks, you call the css function to show the whole div? using jquery would be something like this.

```
$(".reserva").on("click", function () {
    $(".reserva-container").eq(0).css("display", "block/inline/flex/grid/...")
});
```

Comment: Because I want the div to show the informations of the clicked laboratory. When I click on the button "reservar" I need to use the informations off my back end, so I need to generate this div with INNERHTML. I'm doing that, but some animations is not working because it's depends on other js file. I don't know how to fix that 