# How do I link to a javascript file within a javascript file?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you dynamically load a javascript file? (Think C's #include)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-think-cs-include)
>   [Include JavaScript file inside JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

I know that one can link to external javascript files with html code akin to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://external.com/code.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to do this within a javascript (.js) file?

Comment: may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-think-cs-include

Comment: Thanks, but I think neither method is working for my example using the Google Visualization API: http://jsfiddle.net/V9jdu/

Answer (score 3):

Create a `script` element and append it to the DOM. That should load your other script.

```
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
newScript.setAttribute("src","http://external.com/code.js");
body.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's working for my example: http://jsfiddle.net/V9jdu/

Comment: Note that in HTML5 the `type` attribute is not used.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the answer given in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/272193)