# Javascript equivalent of php's include?

Tags: javascript

In php there is a

```
<?php include("file.php"); ?>
```

Is there an equivalent in javascript.

Comment: php.js is the answer http://phpjs.org

Comment: Which environment are you using JavaScript in? In a browser? On a server using Node.js? There are different techniques for each.

Comment: browser. And no jquery

Comment: Take a look at require.js -> http://requirejs.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297688/load-javascript-like-phps-include or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-think-of-include-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is :

```
<script src="path-to-your-js"></script>
```

Or you can take a look at [Require.js](http://requirejs.org)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using an asset precompilation framework such as [Broccoli](https://github.com/joliss/broccoli).