# How can I dynamically connect LightTable to an external browser from console?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, lighttable

I want to try out some of the new ECMAScript features but the browser integrated with LightTable doesn't have those features. For that I need to connect to an external browser and for that LightTable requires this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws' src='http://localhost:53742/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>
```

I tried:

```
document.head.innerHTML+="<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws' src='http://localhost:53742/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>"
```

But LightTable still doesn't see the connection:

> "No client available. We don't know what kind of client you want for
>   this one. Try starting a client by choosing one of the connection
>   types in the connect panel."

How can I change this into JavaScript code that can be pasted in the console tab, so that I dynamically connect  LightTable to an external browser from console?

Comment: Just do `document.head.appendChild(…)`

Comment: @Bergi Tried that didn't work, that's why I am here

Comment: What did not work about it?

Comment: @Bergi LightTable still ask me to choose for a client "No client available.

We don't know what kind of client you want for this one. Try starting a client by choosing one of the connection types in the connect panel."

Comment: @Bergi Actually now I see I tried `document.head.innerHTML+="<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws' src='http://localhost:53742/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>"`

Comment: Well [that doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/1048572). Use the DOM methods instead.

Comment: @Bergi If I try `document.head.appendChild("<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws' src='http://localhost:53742/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>")` `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.`

Comment: No, of course [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21320/1048572). `appendChild` takes DOM elements, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for pointing in comments that `innerHTML` doesn't work and I have to use DOM methods instead.
Pasting below code in console connected LightTable with the browser.

The script will need and ask the the port and [because this changes and every window uses a port](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/PEHcuTjydYQ) this needs to be inserted manually.

To see what port you need to introduce:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, type connect, and then select `Connect to a browser`. You'l see the port there displayed in the URL of the HTML piece of code.

```
var port = prompt("What's the port number?");   
var script_tag = document.createElement("script");
script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://localhost:"+port+"/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js");
script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("id", "lt_ws");
document.head.appendChild(script_tag);
```

Also this works also as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar port %3D prompt("What's the port number%3F")%3Bvar script_tag %3D document.createElement("script")%3Bscript_tag.setAttribute("src"%2C "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A"%2Bport%2B"%2Fsocket.io%2Flighttable%2Fws.js")%3Bscript_tag.setAttribute("type"%2C "text%2Fjavascript")%3Bscript_tag.setAttribute("id"%2C "lt_ws")%3Bdocument.head.appendChild(script_tag)%7D)()
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can connect and try or debug things using LightTable on already loaded live pages.