# Load javascript source not working

Tags: javascript, pageload

Hello i need to use JavaScript to load a script tag in the head of my document. The problem is i create the script element fine, but this source is not loaded once the rest of the javascript executes. Is there a better way to load the script before the rest of the JS executes?

```
<script>
var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.src = '../EmergencyBroadcastScripts/source/jquery-1.10.1.min.js';
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(jQ);
            $.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();
            });
    </script>
```

This code will produce the error *"$.noConflict is not a function"* because its not loading the JQ script source before it executes my code. This is my problem. Any ideas??

Comment: Use the `onload` event of the freshly added script tag.

Comment: I thought js is asynchronous. so by the time below statements execute script wouldnt have been loaded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Comment: Because by the time your script get's attached to body engine already tried to process `$.noConflict();`. try to add your script in regular `<script>` tags.

Comment: Do i add the onload to the new script element or remaining javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
jQ.onload = function () {
            $.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();
                });
            }
```

I don't know if it will work in this scenario but it works with images on a canvas.

Comment: That was correct, thanks for helping me out, the javascript wait for the jQuery script source to load first, Thank You!