# how to automatically change url of external js file whenever loading

Tags: javascript, html, share, adblock

how to update the external js file whenever loading in async mode. For example lukkr social share buttons

```
<script src="//lukkr.com/website/pf.js?+date+time"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file

Comment: I checket it . It is not similar or duplicate question. anyhow thanks for your action.

Comment: you want to change the url of the script or the file content?

Answer (score -1):

You currently don't have any filters specifically filtering the src URL: 
https://blockadblock.com/search-adblock-filters.php?domaincheck=lukkr.com

Are you sure that script is being filtered? The script doesn't appear to have a name that would get blocked by generic filters either.

If you're still convinced that it's getting blocked a direct string-based filter -- your best bet is to inline the script, as it's extremely short:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
!function lkrsynkr(){var ex=document.createElement("script");ex.type="text/javascript";var _0xebbd=["\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x73\x72\x63","\x2F\x2F\x6C\x75\x6B\x6B\x72\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x77\x65\x62\x73\x69\x74\x65\x2F\x73\x79\x6E\x63\x2E\x6A\x73"];ex[_0xebbd[0]]=true;ex[_0xebbd[1]]=_0xebbd[2];var tx=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];tx.parentNode.insertBefore(ex,tx)}();!function shrsidbr(){var ex=document.createElement("script");ex.type="text/javascript";var _0xc462=["\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x73\x72\x63","\x2F\x2F\x6C\x75\x6B\x6B\x72\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x74\x61\x67\x73\x2F\x73\x69\x64\x65\x2E\x6A\x73"];ex[_0xc462[0]]=true;ex[_0xc462[1]]=_0xc462[2];var tx=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];tx.parentNode.insertBefore(ex,tx)}();
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I read, the question doesn't mention anything about the script being "filtered".

Comment: @greiner The question is tagged "Adblock", and the question is how to dynamically change the URL of an external javascript. Are there any other reasons to do this other than filtering? I note that you are an engineer at Eyeo, creator of Adblock Plus and you just downvoted a post mentioning BlockAdblock.

Comment: If the question is unclear feel free to comment on the question asking for clarification. The question itself, however, doesn't mention anything about interference by ad blockers. Apart from that I find the link you posted quite useful. :)

Comment: @greiner The question isn't unclear. He asked how to automatically change the external URL of a javascript file in the context of adblock. Please follow your own advice if you're having difficulty understanding it. Thanks for the tips on using StackOverflow.