# Loading two javascript files, differently with different partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a single page application. My layout page looks like

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My page</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="page1"></div>
      <div id="page2"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to load two partial views in each div at different instances.

With each partial view, I want to load a javascript file and after removal of that partial view I wanna remove that respective js file too. Is it possible?

Comment: Answers half of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/242607/5894241. But why would you want to add/remove your scripts like this anyway?

Comment: Getting conflicts due to both the files

Comment: What kind of conflict? Variables with same names or methods?

Comment: Methods with same name

Comment: Can't you just change the method names? If not, why?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set these two partial views as two components and make the javascript files into specified components?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code try this

js1.js:

```
var myFunc = new (function() {

    this.test_one = function() {
        alert('one!');
    };

})();
```

js2.js:

```
function test_one(){
 alert('another one');
}
```

In your view :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
myFunc.test_one();
test_one();
</script>
```

hope it may helpful for you.