# Other way to load these scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

**Solved:** Using $.getScript works.

I have this script that will load 2 other scripts if you are on desktop. If you are not on desktop, those scripts won't load. This works fine.

```
(function () {
    // Detects devices
    if (isMobile.apple.device || isMobile.android.device || isMobile.seven_inch || isMobile.windows.device || isMobile.amazon.device) 
    {      
        console.log('Client is mobile. Not loading particles.');
        document.getElementById("warning-mobile").style.display = 'block'; 
    }
    else
    {  
        console.log('Client is desktop. Loading particles.');
        document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://demihypercube.space/js/particles.js'></script>");
        document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://demihypercube.space/js/app.js'></script>");
    }
})();
```

But, document.write is not the best method. Is there another way I can load particles.js and app.js? They need to load in that order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Comment: Have a look at "Lazyload"

Comment: jQuery.getScript()

Comment: @nullqube That works!

Answer (score 1):

This is the general convention

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'url';    

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```