# how to find the part of code in javascript which is calling other javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web-inspector

When i include "snow.js" javascript some additional third party javascripts are also loaded in page.
and when "snow.js" is not used then no third party javascripts are loaded.
how can I find the code in "snow.js" which calls/uses these thrid party javascripts.

The "snow.js" file is a large file and it does not use organised programming format.

[the link to "snow.js" file](http://www.nightfoodbike.com/test/snow.js)

[screenshot of sources when "snow.js" is included in main html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrDcF.jpg)

I am not able to find the code which uses this javascript file so that I can delete that.

Comment: I downloaded snow.js (based on your link) to local and used in my sample html file and it didn't downloaded any extra third party files. Also the link http://www.nightfoodbike.com/test/snow.js doesn't download any other js files based on Google Chrome inspector.

Comment: thanks for responding .It is not downloading a file but chrome inspector shows use of other Js files as shown in screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It was like finding needle in haystack but out of 3500 line code I found by using these steps.

1. "ctrl+f" to search.
2. search "text/javascript" .
3. replace "text/javascript" with space.

this worked for me. I dont know how it exactly worked but I removed the part of code which are used to call another scripts. for reference
[Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786759/8525873)

If anyone understands how this happed exactly please share.