# Javascript: using eval() to load functions dynamically

Tags: javascript, eval

I want to load more than one function dynamically:

```
var str = "function foo() {} function bar() {}";
var functions = eval(???);
functions.foo();
```

Can this be done with eval? I was only successful with a single function.

Comment: What is the use case where you want to use that? Using `eval` for this task is most likely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With eval. [Not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

```js
var str = "function foo() { console.log('foo'); } function bar() { console.log('bar'); }";
eval(str);
foo();
```

You could use an object and put the functions inside. You can later add a function with assignment.

```js
var functions = {
        foo: function () { console.log('foo'); },
        bar: function () { console.log('bar'); }
    };

functions.foo();

functions.baz = function () { console.log('baz'); }

functions.baz();
```

Comment: eval(str) - that easy :D Thx. In the environment where I use it, the evil things of eval do not matter.

Comment: then you can use a mixture of both proposals.

Answer (score 0):

With `functions.foo();` you try to access the property `foo` of the object `functions` and this will give you an `undefined`.

## Solution

You could replace you string of functions simply with an object like

```
var functions = {
   foo: function() {},
   bar: function() {}
}
```

This avoids also the usege of `eval()`.
Now you can access each property with `functions.<functionName>;`. You can add propertys dynamicly at runtime in JavaScript. So there is no usecase for `eval` in your problem

## Example

```js
var functions = {
   foo: function() { console.log('foo') },
   bar: function() { console.log('bar') }
}

function addNewFunction(object, functionName, functionImplementation) {
  object[functionName] = functionImplementation
}

addNewFunction(functions, 'ok', function() { console.log('ok') })

functions.foo()
functions.ok()
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` will execute certain string but it will not return anything. So `functions` will be `undefined`

`eval` will also run the given string in current scope. So the parsed functions will not necessarily be created in global scope.

**Sample:**

```js
var str = "function foo1() {console.log('foo1')} function bar1() {console.log('bar1')}";
var functions = eval(str);
console.log(functions);
foo1();

(function() {
  var str = "function foo2() {console.log('foo2')} function bar2() {console.log('bar2')}";
  var functions = eval(str);
  foo2();
})()
try {
  foo2();
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex.message)
}
```

My suggestion, create a new JS file and load it dynamically.

#### Reference Links:

- [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)
- [Eval is evil](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
- [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

**var foo = '( function foo() {} )'**

**var bar = '( function bar() {} )'**

declare function with variable, then use the eval

**var result = eval(foo)**

result variable get the result of the foo() function